# Phones that support Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I saw an official list that said the Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4 phones support Ubuntu. The thing is, there are all kinds of Galaxy phones. Nexus S, Nexus S2, Nexus S3, and I think S4 is out. Does it work on all these? Some better than others?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no the s, s2, s3 and s4 all have the prefix 'galaxy' (galaxy s, galaxy s2 and so on). There is only one galaxy nexus from samsung.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of Nexus phones that is manufactured by Samsung is 'Galaxy Nexus'.
Newer Nexus phone are 'Nexus 4' (LG). Olders are 'Nexus One' (HTC) and 'Nexus S' (Samsung).
There is no Nexus S1/S2/S3. Probably you mean Samsung Galaxy S1/S2/S3 that they are not Nexus device (i.e Google doesn't support them directly).

Comment: Thanks. I find the whole naming convention confusing (Galaxy vs Nexus).